# geofencing intent service not working android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-geofence, android-gps

I am trying to develop a **geofencing** feature in my android app(Native android with java). I am using geofencing option for the first time and testing on **real device** (Redmi note4) with mocking locations with an app. **Mock location** works perfect but my **pending intent service** never calls onHandleIntent() method. I followed the android developers site to develop the functionality.

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
....
<service android:name=".util.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService"/>
```

Geofence Pending intent service

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {
/**
 * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
 *
 * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
 */

private static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitions";

public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService() {
    super("GeofenceTransitions");
}



protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if(!isIntentServiceRunning) {
        isIntentServiceRunning = true;
    }
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        String errorMessage = "Error" + geofencingEvent.getErrorCode();
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, errorMessage);
        return;
    }

    // Get the transition type.
    int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

    // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
    if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
            geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

        // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger
        // multiple geofences.
        List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

        String geofenceTransitionDetails = "", geoTransition = "";
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {
            // Get the transition details as a String.
            geoTransition = "Enter";
            geofenceTransitionDetails = "Enter transition";
        }
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT){
            geoTransition = "Exit";
            geofenceTransitionDetails = "Exit transition";
        }

        // Send notification and log the transition details.
        showNotification(geoTransition, geofenceTransitionDetails);
        Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
    } else {
        // Log the error.
        showNotification("ERROR", "ERROR");
        Log.e(TAG, "NO ENTER OR EXIT");
    }
}


public void showNotification(String text, String bigText) {

    // 1. Create a NotificationManager
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // 2. Create a PendingIntent for AllGeofencesActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // 3. Create and send a notification
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(text)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(bigText))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    isIntentServiceRunning = false;
    Log.d("INTENET SERVICE", "ON DESTROY");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    isIntentServiceRunning = true;
    Log.d("INTENET SERVICE", "ON CREATE");
}

@Override
public void onStart(@Nullable Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Log.d("INTENET SERVICE", "ON START");
    isIntentServiceRunning = true;
}
```

}

Main activity, from where i add geofence.

```
mGeofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);
GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());
    Location mLocation = gpsTracker.getLocation();
    if (mLocation != null) {

        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Geofence Lat : " + mLocation.getLatitude() + " Lng : " + mLocation.getLongitude());
        mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                // geofence.
                .setRequestId("placeId")

                .setCircularRegion(
                        mLocation.getLatitude(),
                        mLocation.getLongitude(),
                        Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                )
                .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .build());


        mGeofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent())
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d("GEOFENCE", "ADDED");
                        // Geofences added
                        // ...
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d("GEOFENCE", "NOT ADDED");
                        // Failed to add geofences
                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }



private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}

private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when
    // calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
    mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.
            FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Log.d("GEOFENCE", "PENDING INTENT CREATED");
    return mGeofencePendingIntent;
}
```

**GPSTracker** is my custom utility class i am using to get location.

Comment: @Pramoda have you resolved this issue? If yes, Please share, I am facing same issue. 
Thanks in advance